# JS browser game - avoid initializing all objects

Tags: javascript

I followed a tutorial on how to build basic games by using JS/HTML and now I am expanding it : [Game](https://pages.github.ccs.neu.edu/pamousset/spaceGame./?fbclid=IwAR1P59hWw8SNADg2z5ySAO056LOulpCDgHH0nt4ogana3zqYLzX_zFzoqVU). (click on space to fire, right arrow to move on the right and left one to move on your left)

I have:

- 1 `#hero`
- 1 array of `#enemies` that stores `.enemies` objects
- 1 array of  `#lifes` that stores `.life` objects

I added more than 30 `.enemies` objects in my `#enemies` array, and I feel an impact on the speed of the page when the game is running. What would be the most efficient way to not add `.enemies` objects in my `#enemies` array gradually?

```
var hero = {
    top : 700,
    left : 550
};


var missiles = [];

var enemies = [
{left: 700, top: -100},
{left: 500, top: -200},
{left: 200, top: -300},
{left: 700, top: -400},
{left: 400, top: -500},
{left: 800, top: -600},
{left: 200, top: -900},
{left: 250, top: -900},
{left: 120, top: -900},
{left: 160, top: -900},
{left: 280, top: -900},
{left: 330, top: -900},
{left: 330, top: -1100},
{left: 280, top: -1500},
{left: 800, top: -1500},
{left: 500, top: -1500},
{left: 700, top: -1550},
{left: 60, top: -1550},
{left: 560, top: -1600},
{left: 60, top: -1750},
{left: 900, top: -1700},
{left: 150, top: -1950},
{left: 200, top: -1960},
{left: 250, top: -1980},
{left: 50, top: -2500},
{left: 100, top: -2500},
{left: 150, top: -2500},
{left: 200, top: -2540},
{left: 250, top: -2580},
{left: 300, top: -2580},
{left: 350, top: -2580}
];

var lifes = [
    {left: 400, top: -600},
    {left: 50, top: -1300}

]


let health = document.getElementById("health");


const drawEnemies = () => {
    document.getElementById("enemies").innerHTML = "";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){
        document.getElementById('enemies').innerHTML +=
        `
        <div class="enemy" style='
        left:${enemies[i].left}px;
        top: ${enemies[i].top}px;
        '></div>
        `;
    }
}

const drawLifes = () => {
    document.getElementById("lifes").innerHTML = "";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < lifes.length ; i ++){
        document.getElementById('lifes').innerHTML += 
        `
        <div class='life' style='left:${lifes[i].left}px; 
        top:${lifes[i].top}px;'>
        </div>
        `;
    }

}

const drawMissiles = () => {

    document.getElementById("missiles").innerHTML = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < missiles.length ; i++){
        document.getElementById('missiles').innerHTML += 
        `
        <div class='missile' style='left:${missiles[i].left}px; 
        top:${missiles[i].top}px;'>
        </div>
        `;

        missiles[i].top
        missiles[i].left
    }
}

const drawHero = () => {
    document.onkeydown = function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 65){
            health.value -=10;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 37){
            hero.left = hero.left - 30;
            moveHero();

        }
        else if(e.keyCode ==39){
            hero.left = hero.left + 30;
            moveHero();

        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 32){
            missiles.push(
                {
                    left: hero.left + 25,
                    top: hero.top - 30
                }
            );
            drawMissiles();          
        }
    }
}



const moveEnemies = () => {

    for(var i = 0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){
        enemies[i].top += 2;
        if(enemies[i].top > 700){
            health.value -= 10;
            enemies.splice(i,1);
            if(health.value <= 0){
                alert("GAME OVER");
                document.location.reload();
            }

        }
    }

}

const moveHero = () => {
    document.getElementById("hero").style.left = hero.left + "px";
}

const moveMissiles = () =>{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < missiles.length ; i++){
        missiles[i].top -= 10;
    }
}

const moveLifes= () =>{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < lifes.length ; i++){
        lifes[i].top += 1;
    }
}

const explosion = (topEn, leftEn, delay = 300) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'explosion';
    div.style.top = topEn + 'px';
    div.style.left = leftEn + 'px';

    document.getElementById('explosions').append(div);
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.remove()
    }, delay);
  }



const collisionDetector = () => {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){
        for(var j = 0 ; j < missiles.length ; j++){
            if(
                (missiles[j].top <= enemies[i].top + 50) &&
                (missiles[j].top >= enemies[i].top) &&
                (missiles[j].left >= enemies[i].left) &&
                (missiles[j].left <= enemies[i].left +50)
            ){
                explosion(enemies[i].top, enemies[i].left);
                enemies.splice(i, 1);
                missiles.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
}

const lifeEating = () => {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < lifes.length ; i++){
        if(
            (lifes[i].top >= hero.top -60) &&
            (lifes[i].left >= hero.left) &&
            (lifes[i].left <= hero.left +50)
        ){
            health.value += 20;
            lifes.splice(i,1);
        }

    }
}



const gameLoop = () => {
    setTimeout(gameLoop,20);
    moveMissiles();
    drawMissiles();
    moveEnemies();
    drawEnemies();
    moveLifes();
    drawLifes();
    collisionDetector();
    lifeEating();
}

const app = () => {
    drawHero();
    drawEnemies();
    gameLoop();
}


app();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding objects to an array won't really cause a slowdown, but excessively updating the HTML on the page will. Try this as your darwEnemies function instead:

```
const drawEnemies = () => {
    var htmlToAdd = "";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){
        htmlToAdd +=
        `
        <div class="enemy" style='
        left:${enemies[i].left}px;
        top: ${enemies[i].top}px;
        '></div>
        `;
    }
    document.getElementById('enemies').innerHTML = htmlToAdd;
}
```

For 30 enemies, this function now updates the HTML once instead of 31 times because we're now updating a variable in the for loop instead of the page's HTML itself. You can do the same thing with drawLifes() and drawMissles().

```
const drawLifes = () => {
    var htmlToAdd = "";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < lifes.length ; i ++){
        htmlToAdd += 
        `
        <div class='life' style='left:${lifes[i].left}px; 
        top:${lifes[i].top}px;'>
        </div>
        `;
    }
    document.getElementById("lifes").innerHTML = htmlToAdd;

}

const drawMissiles = () => {

    var htmlToAdd = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < missiles.length ; i++){
        htmlToAdd += 
        `
        <div class='missile' style='left:${missiles[i].left}px; 
        top:${missiles[i].top}px;'>
        </div>
        `;

        missiles[i].top
        missiles[i].left
    }
    document.getElementById('missiles').innerHTML = htmlToAdd;
}
```

To add faster enemies, add a "framerate" property to each object in enemies.

```
var enemies = [
{framerate: 1, left: 700, top: -100},
{framerate: 1, left: 500, top: -200},
{framerate: 1, left: 200, top: -300},
{framerate: 1, left: 700, top: -400},
{framerate: 1, left: 400, top: -500},
{framerate: 2, left: 800, top: -600},
{framerate: 2, left: 200, top: -900},
{framerate: 2, left: 250, top: -900},
{framerate: 2, left: 120, top: -900},
{framerate: 2, left: 160, top: -900},
{framerate: 2, left: 280, top: -900},
{framerate: 2, left: 330, top: -900},
{framerate: 2, left: 330, top: -1100},
{framerate: 2, left: 280, top: -1500},
{framerate: 2, left: 800, top: -1500},
{framerate: 2, left: 500, top: -1500},
{framerate: 2, left: 700, top: -1550},
{framerate: 2, left: 60, top: -1550},
{framerate: 2, left: 560, top: -1600},
{framerate: 2, left: 60, top: -1750},
{framerate: 2, left: 900, top: -1700},
{framerate: 2, left: 150, top: -1950},
{framerate: 2, left: 200, top: -1960},
{framerate: 2, left: 250, top: -1980},
{framerate: 2, left: 50, top: -2500},
{framerate: 2, left: 100, top: -2500},
{framerate: 2, left: 150, top: -2500},
{framerate: 2, left: 200, top: -2540},
{framerate: 2, left: 250, top: -2580},
{framerate: 2, left: 300, top: -2580},
{framerate: 2, left: 350, top: -2580}
];
```

That will give us something to reference in the moveEnemies function to tell us how often to move each enemy.

```
var frame = 0;
const moveEnemies = () => {
    frame++;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){
        if(frame % enemies[i].framerate == 0){
            enemies[i].top += 2;
            if(enemies[i].top > 700){
                health.value -= 10;
                enemies.splice(i,1);
                if(health.value <= 0){
                    alert("GAME OVER");
                    document.location.reload();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the enemy's framerate is 2, we only move that enemy every second frame. Because all of your enemies were already moving every single frame, this code won't really speed any enemies up but rather slow some of them down. To speed them up, increase how often the game runs, like so:

```
const gameLoop = () => {
    setTimeout(gameLoop,10);//used to be 20
    moveMissiles();
    drawMissiles();
    moveEnemies();
    drawEnemies();
    moveLifes();
    drawLifes();
    collisionDetector();
    lifeEating();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron, it is better now. Do you know what would be the most efficient way to add different type of enemies (same parameters but move faster) ? Right now I only 1 kind of enemy.  I know how to do it in Java, I would have an Interface "Ennemies" and probably few EnnemiesType classes that implement Ennemies but not sure how can I handle it in my case.

Comment: I'll update my answer with how I'd do it in a couple minutes. Also, If you have the time to reply to this comment later with a link to the game running smoothly with more enemies that would be cool.

Comment: Updated. It's better, probably will also try the ASYNC/AWAIT strategy as well

Comment: Updated my answer to include faster enemies as well. I'm fine with not being the accepted answer anymore, but it did seem like I helped some. Would you mind giving it an upvote at least? Appreciated.

Comment: Amazing man thank you for your help! Do you know where I can learn about making browser games like that? Like next steep, I will probably want to make a "boss" which will behave totally differently, then create set of levels, then probably     different attacks...

Answer (score 0):

To draw the enemies gradually and render then one by one on an interval you can use JS [ASYNC/AWAIT](https://javascript.info/async-await)
So what you have to do is:

1. use this function

   ```
   const sleep = ms => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
   }
   ```
2. Use this function inside **drawEnemies** function to stop the code for a certain amount of time after drawing each enemy

   ```
   const drawEnemies = async () => {
   document.getElementById("enemies").innerHTML = "";
   for(var i = 0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){
       document.getElementById('enemies').innerHTML +=
       `
       <div class="enemy" style='
       left:${enemies[i].left}px;
       top: ${enemies[i].top}px;
       '></div>
       `;
      await sleep(500) // waits for half a second
   }
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to add async/await to other functions for the code to work properly.

Every function that uses **await** must be declared to be an **async** function and when we call an async function we must **await** for it.

```
    const gameLoop = async () => {
    setTimeout(gameLoop,20);
    moveMissiles();
    drawMissiles();
    moveEnemies();
    await drawEnemies();
    moveLifes();
    drawLifes();
    collisionDetector();
    lifeEating();
    }
```